# Ffmpeg Split lost one second

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, split

I got a problem with ffmpeg video cutting. Videos not cut properly. 1 second between the first and second video is lost.
part1.avi split code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part1.avi
```

part2.avi split code

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part2.avi
```

ffmpeg -i part1.avi = 00:01:00.02
ffmpeg -i part2.avi = 00:01:00.02

Comment: Can you check if the audio stream and the video stream are the same duration after cutting? You can get this info with tools such as [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Please provide the complete ffmpeg console outputs.

Comment: Part1 console output:http://tny.cz/ebf2cc00
Part2 console output:http://tny.cz/f1076518
Part1 mediainfo(mplayer):http://tny.cz/d34a2cf9
Part2 mediainfo(mplayer):http://tny.cz/bf4b56b4

Comment: Shred files from different servers to handle. Processed want to merge the files again.
I know very little english.